# Having trouble updating SetMultiValuedProfileProperty in a powerapps flow

Tags: power-automate, powerapps, powerapps-formula, sharepoint-userprofile

I am not having any luck finding information on how to specify the propertyValues in the json for updating a multi value field. the field is also tied to a term set. I can update it as a single value, but running into issues trying to update as a multi value.

{
'accountName': "i:0#.f|membership|chackett@cmhcm.org",
'propertyName': 'TeamName',
'propertyValues': 'Network Support'
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyyvA.png)

I'm at a loss, I found some information on using an IList, but everything I try continues to throw errors when running the flow.